# How to use Apache Camel to copy files from S3 located in cross account

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, apache-camel, amazon-iam

I have a requirement to copy files from/to s3 located in a different aws account using Apache Camel.

For instance I am running Camel in Account A and S3 is present in Account B.
I have created a cross account role to access S3 from Account A.

Initially I created an s3Client using STS and set it in camel registry to access the S3 from Account B. As these are temporary credentials, they can expire any time before completion of copy job. In such case what should I do? Is there a way to update the s3-client in camel registry while running the route?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Camel has support to take s3client to connect to AWS S3. As the problem here is to access S3 from cross account, First we have to create a role in Account B with Account A as trusted account. Make sure to provide required S3 access to this role through policies.

Now create a policy in account A as below to assume role.

```
     {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
              {
                  "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                  "Effect": "Allow",
                  "Action": [
                      "sts:AssumeRole",
                      "sts:GetSessionToken"
                  ],
                  "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::Account_B:role/Cross-account-s3-access"
              }
          ]
      }
```

Create a role in account A and attach this policy to newly created role. Assign this policy to ec2 instance where the camel (applicable to any app which requires a cross account access)  is deployed.

Now we can generate temporary credentials through any STS API and use those credentials to access the resources from cross account(In this case we can access S3 from Account B).

As these credentials can expire after specific time, we need to look into a way to refresh them. AWS has provided **STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider** API that would refresh the credentials automatically. below is the code snippet for that

```
   Builder builder = new STSAssumeRoleSessionCredentialsProvider.Builder(roleArn, roleSession).withRoleSessionDurationSeconds(900);
    return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
    .withCredentials(builder.build())
    .withRegion(region)
    .build();
```